# TypeError: required field "posonlyargs" missing from arguments error running a Pytest Script on Python 3.8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I created a Simple Selenium Pytest automation script on Python 3.8.1. After running the script I see the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.
Error messages
.
.
TypeError: required field "posonlyargs" missing from arguments
```

I googled and saw that this seems to be an issue with Python 3.8.1. Any suggestions on how to avoid this error? I could always go back to the previous Python version (3.8.0), but I'm keeping that as the last option.

Answer (score 4):

This error message...

```
TypeError: required field "posonlyargs" missing from arguments
```

...implies that `posonlyargs` were missing from the arguments when defining function on Python 3.8

---

### Deep dive

@carmenbianca in this [merge](https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/pull/3304) mentioned as per the Python docs `ast.arguments` was changed to also take `posonlyargs` as argument. Different [parsers](https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/blob/master/xonsh/parser.py) are loaded depending on the base version of Python. The parser for Python 3.8 was required which would inherit from the v36 parser to adapt to the changes incorporated inorder to address this [issue](https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/issues/3271).

---

### Solution

This issue was addressed through:

- [Python 3.8.0 beta 2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-8-0-beta-2): [bpo-37221](https://bugs.python.org/issue37221): The new function [`PyCode_NewWithPosOnlyArgs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/code.html#c.PyCode_NewWithPosOnlyArgs) allows to create code objects like [`PyCode_New()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/code.html#c.PyCode_New), but with an extra posonlyargcount parameter for indicating the number of positonal-only arguments.
- [Python 3.8.0 beta 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-8-0-beta-3): [bpo-37593](https://bugs.python.org/issue37593): Swap the positions of the posonlyargs and args parameters in the constructor of ast.parameters nodes.

> However, as per best practices you should upgrade to [Python 3.8.1 final](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-8-1-final) *Release date: 2019-12-18*