# Odoo12: TypeError: required field "posonlyargs" missing from arguments

Tags: typeerror, odoo, odoo-12

I'm trying to start the server after restoring the database with `pg_dump` but getting this error in Odoo12 `TypeError: required field "posonlyargs" missing from arguments`, How can i fix this error?

Comment: What python version you are using? check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59564990/typeerror-required-field-posonlyargs-missing-from-arguments-error-running-a-p) and this [reported issue](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/40232) in odoo

Answer (score 0):

change python version and check, Its may be work,It works for me